# CSS TranslateX doesn't move to the right of div

Tags: css, animation, responsive

I'm trying to get the toggle to move it 100% to the right. As I'm trying to make it responsive, I can't set it to move an xx amount of pixels.

Can you please help?

```
input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lc1tdhgb/1/

Thanks

Comment: Something like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/671jk3v2/ .... If yes, I can explain in an answer for you

Comment: @mattdaspy YES! Thank you. I kept trying Right 100%. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('togBtn').checked = true;
}, 1000)
```

```css
#toggle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.switch {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  /*min-height: 32px;*/
  height: auto;
  top: 0;
}

.switch input {
  display: none;
}

.slider {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ca2222;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
  border-radius: 32px;
  padding: 12px 0;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 1.1em;
  width: 1.1em;
  left: 3px;
  bottom: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #3eab37;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  left: calc(100% - 20px);
  /*-webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);*/
}


/*------ ADDED CSS ---------*/

.slider:after {
  content: 'OFF';
  color: white;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}

input:checked+.slider:after {
  content: 'ON';
}


/*--------- END --------*/
```

```html
<div id="toggle">
  <label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" id="togBtn"><div class="slider round"></div></label>
</div>
```

Well, just make sure that the container of the elements follow a `position: relative;`, so the wrapper have the restrains for the `absolute` elements inside of it. Then, `right` is actually how far from right you want the element to be, in this case, you could've used either `right: 0%;` or `left: 100%;` although you've encountered the error in the fact that you'd be ignoring margins from the parent's style. That's why I added `left: calc(100% - 20px);` (20px was on trial and error, until I got it aligned with the outter border of the switch!), then now it works as wanted. Glad to help :)